# How to dynamically construct and set options for dijit.form.select widget?

Tags: java, javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have a select widget as follows

```
var pulseLen = new Select({
    id : "_PulseLength",
    label:"PulseLength",
    name: "pulseLength",
    value : 100,
    options: [
              { label : "5", value :"5" },
              { label : "10", value :"10" },
              { label : "30", value :"30" },
              { label : "100", value :"100" },
              { label : "300", value :"300" }
              ]
        });
```

Now based on the value selected in the above pulseLength widget i have to change the options of the below Select Range widget
Its part of GUI validations.

```
   var range = new Select({
          id:"_Range",
          label:"Range"),
          name: "range",
          value: "5000",
        options: [
          { label : "5", value :"5000" },
          { label : "10", value :"10000" },
          { label : "20", value :"20000" },
          { label : "40", value :"40000" },
          { label : "80", value :"80000" },
          { label : "160", value :"160000" },
          { label : "260", value :"260000" }
          ]
});
```

API to generate dynamic options

```
 function getRangeArray(pulselen){

    var myOptions = "";
    var array = [0.5,1,2,5,10,20,40];
    console.log("Length got is " + pulselen);
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        var myTmp = "{label : '" + array[i] + "', value : '"+array[i] * 1000 + "'}";
        //console.log(myTmp);
        if(i==array.length-1){

            myOptions = myOptions + myTmp;
        }else{
            myTmp=myTmp+",";
            myOptions = myOptions + myTmp;  
        }

        //console.log(myOptions);
    }

    //console.log(myOptions);
    myOptions = "[" + myOptions + "];";
    return myOptions;
}
```

OnChange event of the pulseLength trying to change the options

```
  var newOptions = getRangeArray(value);
  console.log(newOptions);
  registry.byId("_Range").set("options", newOptions);
```

Sample Output

```
[{label : '0.5', value : '500'},
 {label : '1', value : '1000'},
 {label : '2', value : '2000'},
 {label : '5', value : '5000'},
 {label : '10', value : '10000'},
 {label : '20', value : '20000'},
 {label : '40', value : '40000'}];
```

Comment: what version of Dojo?... especially if you have to hack widget internals, this really matters

Comment: The range select widget has a ; after "value:" and a ) after "label: Range".  Is this just a typo?

Comment: Should i typecast it as objects ?? Im using DOJO 1.9

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here, I think. Like Thomas Kagan said in the comments, there are some typos:

> The range select widget has a ; after "value:" and a ) after "label:
>   Range".

Next, in your getRangeArray function, you are actually building a string! That's not necessary - you would have to parse it with `JSON.parse` to be useful. Instead, just build the array with objects directly:

```
function getRangeArray(pulselen){

    var myOptions = [];
    var array = [0.5,1,2,5,10,20,40];
    console.log("Length got is " + pulselen);
    for(i=0;i<array.length;i++){
        myOptions.push({label: array[i].toString(), value: "" + array[i]*1000 });
    }
    return myOptions;
}
```

Notice that I call `toString()` on the labels! Otherwise dijit/form/Select will throw some really weird errors - it expects the labels to be strings.

Also, although I don't know if it's necessary, you may have to call `reset()` on the `_Range` widget after updating its options:

```
registry.byId("_Range").set("options", newOptions).reset();
```

.. at least you used to, but it seems to work without it now.

Here's a fiddle with your code, and the updated parts: http://jsfiddle.net/ycrz1ug4/